# How do I use a complex context with Django?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-context

I'm learning Django by building simple contact manager, 
I use Django 1.7.3 with Python 2.7.
I'm confused about how to render the template with the given context.

```
context = {
    'name': 'John Doe',
    'age': 24,
    'email_ids' : [
        {
            'use': 'personal',
            'email': 'johndoe@example.com' 
        },
        {
            'use': 'work',
            'email': 'manager@example.com'
        },
        {
            'use': 'spam',
            'email': 'iwantyournewsletter@example.com'
        }
    ]
    'phones': [
        {
            'use': 'personal',
            'number': '+1234567890'
        },
        {
            'use': 'work',
            'number': '+1234567891'
        }
    ]
}
```

My template block is,

```
{% block  address_slot %}
    Name : {{ name }}
    Age : {{ age }}
    Email Address:
        {{ use }} : {{ email }}
    Phone Number: 
        {{ use}}  : {{ number }}
{% endblock %}
```

I'm not sure how to insert the dict (email details and the number details) inside the list (`email_ids` and `phones`) in the context, While I got the name and age inserted.

In python I use

```
for email in context['email_ids']:
    print(email['email_ids'])
```

To print the emails while what is the equivalent in Django templates?

How can I insert the email address in the related field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `{% for %}` template tag and dot notation to look up keys in each dictionary, EG:

```
{% for email_id in email_ids %}
  Email Address:
    {{ email_id.use }} : {{ email_id.email }}
{% endfor %}
```